# Instance is not passed to the `__call__` function of a callable class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why `ClassWithCallable` instance isn't passed to the `__call__` function? How can I make that happen?

```
class Callable:
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self, args, kwargs)
        print('Where is `ClassWithCallable` instance?')


class ClassWithCallable:
    method = Callable()


instance = ClassWithCallable()
instance.method('some', data='data')
instance.method(instance, 'some', data='data') #  ugly :(
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Callable object at 0x7f2b4e5ecfd0> ('some',) {'data': 'data'}
Where is `ClassWithCallable` instance?
<__main__.Callable object at 0x7fef7fa49fd0> (<__main__.ClassWithCallable object at 0x7fef7fa49fa0>, 'some') {'data': 'data'}
```

Comment: self is the instance of callable ... whats your question? why do you expect it to know what the parent class is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to "bind" `self`, you need to implement the descriptor protocol (similar to how an actual method works!)

```py
class Callable:
    def __init__(self, inst=None):
        self.inst = inst

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return type(self)(instance)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.inst, args, kwargs)


class C:
    callable = Callable()


C().callable(1, a=2)
```

when the attribute is retrieved, it calls the `__get__` of your descriptor -- my implementation returns a "bound" version of `Callable` where `self.inst` is the `self` you seek

example output:

```
$ python3 t.py
<__main__.C object at 0x7f3051529dc0> (1,) {'a': 2}
```